# ActiveMQ get dequeued or consumed messages

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, jms-topic

Is there any way to get the consumed message,i want to get All messages since the start of the ActiveMQ

Answer (score 1):

Once a message is consumed it is gone, the broker marks it as consumed and the storage location it was in is dropped or reused.